# How to create objects for all JUnit tests?

Tags: java, testing, junit

While creating JUnit test cases, it takes a long time to reconstruct objects for every single one of them and perform some operations that all my unit tests use.
Is there anyway I can make some objects in a test case that I can freely use in all of my tests without recreating them each time?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that tests are just code. So you can use the same patterns that you use in all of your other code when you need something that you can reuse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple way of doing this is to create a private method that creates test objects. These can take in the parameters (the ones that need to change in the various test cases), or just provide a default object that you could in turn change. If the same objects are used in multiple tests, then a testdata-builder might be what you are looking for.

Say you have a class like this:

```
public class Something {
    private String someString;
    private Integer someInt;

    public Something(final String someString, final Integer someInt) {
        this.someString = someString;
        this.someInt = someInt;
    }
    //getters and stuff
 }
```

Then you can create a testdata builder like this:

```
 public class SomethingBuilder {
     private String someString;
     private Integer someInt;

     public SomethingBuilder() {
         someString = "Some default value";
         someInt = 42;
     }

     public SomethingBuilder withSomeString(final String someString) {
         this.someString = someString;
         return this;
     }

     public SomethingBuilder withSomeInt(final Integer someInt) {
         this.someInt = someInt;
         return this;
     }

     public Something build() {
         final Something something = new Something(someString, someInt);
         return something;
     }
 }
```

Then, creating test data becomes really simple, you can mutate the fields you different than your default values easily:

```
 final Something something = 
      new SomethingBuilder().withSomeString("I want to override the default!").build();
```

Might seem like a bit of overkill for my small, example class, but if you have a central data class that appears in many tests, it will save you a lot of time and lines of code.